# Segue to UIViewController in different UINavigationController

Tags: swift, segue

I have the following setup:

[image]

I have a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.  I have a second `UIViewController` embedded in a second `UINavigationController`.  I need to call the second `UIViewController` in two ways.  I have two buttons set up on the first `UIViewController`.  The first button has a segue created by control-click-drag between the button and the second `UINavigationController`.  When I click the button, the second view controller displays.  The second button calls the created segue using `performSegueWithIdentifier` like this:

```
@IBAction func segueTwoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowSecondView", sender: self)
}
```

In both cases the second view controller displays correctly.

But, I have some information that I want to pass.  So in the `prepareForSegue` function, I have this:

```
let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
```

This fails, because the segue is going through the second `UINavigationController` to get to the second `UIViewController`.

I've come up with two ways of handling this.

1. I can use the following in the `prepareForSegue`
       let vc = segue.destinationViewController.childViewControllers[0] as! SecondViewController
2. I can add a `UINavigationController` class and then pipe it through there, but that seems like a lot of work to do this.

Both of these ways work, but is this the best way, or is there some other way that I should consider handling it?

Second question - Assuming that I do it this way and put a `UINavigationController` class in so that I can pass the information along, what is the proper way to unwind?  I can create an unwind segue that will go straight from the second view controller, back to the first, but is it acceptable to do it this way?  Or would I need to unwind to the `UINavigationController` class and then to the first view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you decided to embed another navigation controller within another. Generally, if you embed a navigation controller one time that will suffice for the rest after you've set up your other segues. So first thing's first delete that second nav controller.

Secondly, from experience, I would always avoid control dragging from anything other the view controller itself. Otherwise, you get duplicate calls to perform segues. So go ahead and delete all remnants of the prior segues you created with the buttons. Instead, Control drag from the top yellow view controller icon to the next view controller. make sure you name the segue arrow so that you can properly performsegueWithIdentifier

Now you should have First View directly segued to the Second View. This will be easier to pipe or funnel information through the segue function exactly like you had coded above

```
   let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
```

Comment: I did it that way because I like how the view controller slides up, instead of left.  I've tried working with custom transitions before, but the only ones that I could ever get working don't have the navigation bar.  I've yet to find a decent, basic tutorial on custom transitions.  They all do a bunch of "fancy" transitions that I don't want or care about.  All I've ever really wanted to do with transitions is control the direction from which the view slides.

Comment: Oh okay cool! Didn't know about that effect. So, what you can do is instead of funneling your information through segues (which I personally find cumbersome at times) is you can set up a global object that keeps track of information for you. Lets the take the following as an example:

Answer (score 0):

Global Variable ( will replace segue funneling information )

Lets take this as an example. Say I wanted to recored the user's name on the first view controller.

```
// First View Controller
private let userName: String

// After that we can create a new object called NameSingleton
class NameSingleton {

// NameSingleton.swift
var UserName:String = " " // Since its global this value will change
static let sharedinstance = NameSingleton()

}

// Now hop back over to your first ViewController 
// before you trigger your segue assign whatever data you need to your 
// singleton. In this case, a name.

// First View Controller.swift


@IBAction func segueTwoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
NameSingleton.sharedInstance.UserName = "Hi"
performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowSecondView", sender: self)
}

// Now if you go to the second view controller and access it, the name  
// will be stored in the singleton. (Great for moving huge pieces info   
// (i.e. structs, objects, lists)
```